# Find the integral under the region $3x<4y, 0<x<1,0<y<1, f(x,y)=p^2(xy)^{p-1}$

Tags: integration

The solution did $$\int _0^1\int _{\frac{3}{4}x}^1p^2\left(xy\right)^{p-1}dy\:dx\:\: = 1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^\theta.$$

What I did was $$\int _0^1\int _0^{\frac{4}{3}y}p^2\left(xy\right)^{p-1}dx\:dy\:\:=\frac{2^{2p-1}}{3^p}.$$

Why is it completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 4  3>1$. When $x$ is close to $\frac {4y} 3$ and $y$ is close to $1$ you get values of $x$ greater than $1$. That is the reason your limits of integration are not correct.

To correct the mistake you have to take $\int_0^{3/4} \int_0^{4y/3}dxdy+\int_{3/4}^{1} \int_0^{1}dxdy$

Comment: so what should the limit be if I'm integrating x first?

Comment: @smaillis I have edited. You will need two separte double integrals.